# Estimating a confidence interval around the average of an interacted treatment effect

Tags: r, regression, confidence-interval, interaction, causality

I've got a causal inference situation with heterogeneous treatment effects.  In addition to simply estimating coefficients, I'd like to get an average effect of the treatment at the covariate values that I observed in my dataset.  For example:
$$
y = \alpha+\beta_1 T + \beta_2Z + \beta_3 (T\times Z) + X'\gamma + \epsilon
$$
I want to know the effect of the treatment $T$ (binary) across the gradient of $Z$ (continuous) that I observe.  The expectation is the average of linear combinations -- that's easy.  But the spread of the estimate seems a bit tricky.  I think I've come up with a reasonable method -- basically take the parameter covariance matrix only for the treatment and the interacted variables, and use that to get the variances of each linear combination of data-parameter groups that I observe, sum those variances, get an SE, and make CI's like normal.  it should work because 
$$
var\left(\displaystyle\sum X'\beta\right) = \displaystyle\sum var\left(X'\beta\right) = \displaystyle\sum X'V_pX
$$
where $\beta$, $X$, and $V_p$ are only the subsets of the $\beta$'s, X's and the parameter covariance matrix that correspond to either the treatment or the interaction(s).
Here's is silly little example in R:

```
#Population model
set.seed(413)
d = data.frame(
    T = rbinom(1000,1,.5)
    ,Z = runif(1000)
    ,x1 = rnorm(1000)
    ,x2 = rnorm(1000)
    )
y = with(d,10+5*T+5*Z+-10*T*Z + 10*x1+10*x2+rnorm(1000,sd=10))

#Fit linear model
library(mgcv) #using mgcv because the predict lpmatrix functionality is useful, though this is parametric
m = gam(y~T*Z+x1+x2,data=d)
summary(m)
#Caluclate Average treatment effect on the treated
c1 = m$model$T*m$coef[names(m$coef)=="T"]
c2 = m$model$Z*m$model$Z*m$coef[names(m$coef)=="T:Z"]
ATET = (c1+c2)[m$model$T==1]
hist(ATET); abline(v = mean(ATET),lty=2,lwd=2)
lpm = predict(m,type='lpmatrix')
lpm = lpm[,grepl("T",colnames(lpm))]
vcv = vcov(m)
vcv = vcv[grepl("T",colnames(vcv)),grepl("T",colnames(vcv))]
variances = diag((lpm)%*%vcv%*%t(lpm))
variances = variances[m$model$T==1]
se = sqrt(sum(vars))
abline(v=mean(ATET)+se*1.96,col="red",lty=2,lwd=2)
abline(v=mean(ATET)-se*1.96,col="red",lty=2,lwd=2)
```

My basic question:  is this right?  Does my 95% CI have the advertised coverage properties?  I guess that I am more of an applied coder than a proper statistician, so I'd appreciate reassurance from people who are more confident in such matters.

EDIT:  One more question about this -- the parameter covariance matrix that I'm using (cluster-robust) comes with a degree of freedom correction already in it.  Does that justify the assumption that this interval is normally distributed?  Or should I use $t$ with some number of degrees of freedom?  Or would that be double-counting somehow?

Comment: I can't answer regarding your proposed solution, but estimating the average treatment effect, ignoring interaction, has been fairly well established, methodologically, in causal inference. The main options that I'm familiar with are propensity scores, inverse probability weighting, g-methods, and instrumental variables. It may be easier to use one of those methods for your average effect, rather than creating your own solution. Unless you are specifically interested in creating a solution.